# How to set default render for all action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render

My application in many action use `render :nothing => true`. I want be DRY. How can I say to rails by default render nothing for a particular controller?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This might do what you need:

```
before_filter :render_nothing

private
def render_nothing
  render :nothing => true
end
```

`before_filter` and not `after_filter` because the latter is executed after the action finished, which means, after the content was rendered.
Source: http://ap.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods.html#M000128

Comment: If I put it in my controller, code in action not run and I get in log `Filter chain halted as :render_nothing rendered or redirected`

Comment: My first thought is that the filter is being applied on an action that should have it. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714537/filter-chain-halted-as-login-required-rendered-or-redirected

Comment: I don't understand. If I wrote `.., :except => ` then `render_nothing` not run for needed action. But I want run him.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
# put this in a module, or your ApplicationController
def self.nothing_for *actions
   before_filter :only => actions do
      render :nothing => true
   end
end

# This would go in your specific controllers
nothing_for :show, :new, :create
```

Comment: This also not work and put in log `Filter chain halted as #<Proc:0xb271e99c:7>`